# NotSerializableException when trying to write Serializable object to file

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-7.0-nougat

I'm on android and I'm trying to save a list of objects into a file but I always get this exception: *java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.Application*.

I've tried to find what could cause this but all I found is that this error is thrown when trying to serialize a Context object but I'm not even trying to serialize anything related to *Application* or *Context*.

## DataFileManager.java

```
public class DataFileManager implements Serializable {
    public static final String FILE_NAME = "circles.dat";
    private transient final Context ctxt;
    private Set<Save> saves;
    public DataFileManager(Context ctxt) {
        this.ctxt = ctxt;
        this.saves = new HashSet<>();
        reloadSaves();
    }

    public void reloadSaves() {
        File file = file();
        if(file.exists()) {
            try (ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new BufferedInputStream(ctxt.openFileInput(FILE_NAME)))) {
                saves.clear();
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Save save = (Save) reader.readObject();
                        saves.add(save);
                    }
                } catch(EOFException e) {
                } finally {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), "", e);
            }
        } else
            Log.e("load", "file does not exist");
    }

    private void save() {
        try {
            file().createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), "", e);
        }
        try (ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(ctxt.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)))) {
            Iterator<Save> iter = saves.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                Save save = iter.next();
                writer.writeObject(save);
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), "", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), "", e);
        }
    }


    private File file() {
        return ctxt.getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME);
    }


    public Save save(String saveName, Set<Circle> circles) throws SaveAlreadyExistsException {
        if(exists(saveName))
            throw new SaveAlreadyExistsException();
        Save save = createSave(saveName, circles);
        if(!saves.add(save))
            throw new SaveAlreadyExistsException();
        return save;
    }

    public Save forceSave(String saveName, Set<Circle> circles) throws UnknownSaveException {
        Save save;
        if(exists(saveName))
            (save = find(saveName)).overwrite(circles);
        else {
            save = createSave(saveName, circles);
            if(!saves.add(save)) {
                saves.remove(save);
                if(!saves.add(save))
                    throw new UnknownSaveException("Couldn't add Save object to the list");
            }
            save();
        }
        return save;
    }

    private Save createSave(String name, Set<Circle> circles) {
        Save save = new Save(name);
        save.circles.addAll(circles);
        return save;
    }

    public boolean exists(String saveName) {
        return saves.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals(saveName));
    }

    public boolean existsIgnoreCase(String saveName) {
        return saves.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(saveName));
    }

    public Save find(String saveName) {
        return saves.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().equals(saveName)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Save> search(String query) {
        return saves.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Set<Save> getSaves() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(saves);
    }



    public class Save implements Serializable {
        private final String      name;
        private final Set<Circle> circles;

        private Save(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            circles = new HashSet<>();
        }

        public boolean overwrite(Set<Circle> circles) {
            if (circles != null && circles.size() > 0) {
                this.circles.clear();
                this.circles.addAll(circles);
                save();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Set<Circle> getCircles() {
            return circles.stream().map(Circle::clone).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return obj != null && obj instanceof Save && ((Save)obj).name.equals(this.name);
        }
    }

    public static class SaveAlreadyExistsException extends UnknownSaveException {
        public SaveAlreadyExistsException() {
            super("save already exists");
        }
    }

    public static class UnknownSaveException extends Exception {
        private static final String DFLT_MSG = "An unknown error occured";

        public UnknownSaveException() {
            super(DFLT_MSG);
        }

        public UnknownSaveException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }

        public UnknownSaveException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }

        public UnknownSaveException(Throwable cause) {
            super(DFLT_MSG, cause);
        }
    }
}
```

## Circle.java

```
public class Circle implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    private static long nextID = 0;
    private float radius, centerX, centerY;
    private final long id;

    public Circle(float centerX, float centerY) {
        this(centerX, centerY, nextID++);
    }

    private Circle(float centerX, float centerY, long id) {
        this.radius = 0;
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public float getCenterX() {
        return centerX;
    }

    public void setCenterX(float centerX) {
        this.centerX = centerX;
    }

    public float getCenterY() {
        return centerY;
    }

    public void setCenterY(float centerY) {
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    @Override public Circle clone() {
        return new Circle(getCenterX(), getCenterY(), id);
    }

    public boolean isCloneOf(Circle circle) {
        return circle != null && circle != this && this.id == circle.id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof Circle && !isCloneOf((Circle)obj);
    }
}
```

## StackTrace

> E/java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.app.Application
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
>   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>   at com.multimedia.tp3.model.files.DataFileManager.save(DataFileManager.java:77)
>   at com.multimedia.tp3.model.files.DataFileManager.forceSave(DataFileManager.java:116)
>   at com.multimedia.tp3.DrawSurface.save(DrawSurface.java:131)
>   at com.multimedia.tp3.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:95)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6996)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4069)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4116)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Is `Circle` a standalone Java class, or is it an inner class inside something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare `Circle` is an inner class of `DataFileManager`

Comment: You are serializing an inner class somewhere. `file().createNewFile();` is pointless here, and does not throw exceptions. You don't need to iterate the set: you can save the whole thing in one go.

Answer (score 3):

> it's an inner class of DataFileManager

Make it be `public static class` instead of `public class`. Right now, your serialization is choking on the `DataFileManager` that is being serialized, as every `Circle` has an implicit reference back to the outer class instance that created it.

Comment: I'm still get the `NotSerializableException` but now it's really weird cause it throws only the first time I try to save and the objects I'm trying to save are just partially saved (Not only for the first try). Only the position of the circles are saved but not the radius.

Comment: @DrunkenPoney: I cannot really help you with that. You might consider asking a separate question with a fresh [mcve], including the new stack trace. Or, better yet, don't use Java serialization. Use JSON, XML, or SQLite as means of persisting your data.

Comment: Ok I'll try to use JSON or XML and for the stacktrace it's the exact same stacktrace and I realized it appears only the first time cause the debugger console disconnect from the app when it throws

Comment: @DrunkenPoney: Well, it shouldn't be complaining about `android.app.Application` anymore. If it is, then something fairly strange is afoot.